# Get device encryption support information

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to detect the device encryption support in my program. This info is available in the `System Information` program. Please check out the screenshot below:

[image]

What kind of `Win API` functions are used/available to detect the device encryption support? What `System Information` program uses to detect it? I just need some information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: it uses undocumented functions from `fveapi.dll` (Windows Bitlocker Drive Encryption API). It seems to rely only on the TPM capabilities.

---

Note that I only spent like 15 mins on it, but I doubt I missed something crucial, althoug this might be possible.

## A bit of Reverse engineering

Typed `system information` in search bar, saw it spawned `msinfo32.exe`. Put the binary in a disassembler. It uses a MUI file so I'll have to search for the strings in the MUI file and not the executable.

Searching `Device Encryption Support` leads to string ID 951 (0x3b7)

```
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
{
  951,  "Device Encryption Support|%s"
```

Searching for the contant in the disassembler leads to a function named:

```
DeviceEncryptionDataPoints(struct CWMIHelper *, struct CPtrList *)
```

The load ing of the aforementioned string is almost right at the start:

```
.text:00000001400141E9                 mov     edx, 3B7h
.text:00000001400141EE                 lea     rcx, [rsp+2C8h+var_280]
.text:00000001400141F3
.text:00000001400141F3 loc_1400141F3:
.text:00000001400141F3 ;   try {
.text:00000001400141F3                 call    cs:__imp_?LoadStringW@CString@@QEAAHI@Z ; CString::LoadStringW(uint)
```

So we are definitely in the right function.

It loads the `fveapi.dll` module:

```
.text:0000000140014269                 xor     edx, edx        ; hFile
.text:000000014001426B                 mov     r8d, 800h       ; dwFlags
.text:0000000140014271                 lea     rcx, LibFileName ; "fveapi.dll"
.text:0000000140014278                 call    cs:__imp_LoadLibraryExW
```

Gets a pointer on `FveQueryDeviceEncryptionSupport`:

```
.text:00000001400142AB                 lea     rdx, aFvequerydevice ; "FveQueryDeviceEncryptionSupport"
.text:00000001400142B2                 mov     rcx, rdi        ; hModule
.text:00000001400142B5                 call    cs:__imp_GetProcAddress
```

And immediately calls the function (this is a protected CFG call, but it's here):

```
.text:00000001400142CA                 mov     [rsp+2C8h+var_254], rbx
.text:00000001400142CF                 mov     [rsp+2C8h+var_260], 14h
.text:00000001400142D7                 mov     [rsp+2C8h+var_25C], 1
.text:00000001400142DF                 mov     [rsp+2C8h+var_258], 1
.text:00000001400142E7                 lea     rcx, [rsp+2C8h+var_260]
.text:00000001400142EC                 call    cs:__guard_dispatch_icall_fptr
```

## Return value

If the function fails:

```
.text:00000001400142EC                 call    cs:__guard_dispatch_icall_fptr
.text:00000001400142F2                 mov     esi, eax
.text:00000001400142F4                 test    eax, eax
.text:00000001400142F6                 js      loc_1400143F0 ; check failure
```

We land here:

```
.text:00000001400143F7                 mov     edx, 2FFh
.text:00000001400143FC                 lea     rcx, [rsp+2C8h+var_288]
.text:0000000140014401                 call    cs:__imp_?LoadStringW@CString@@QEAAHI@Z ; CString::LoadStringW(uint)
```

The string 0x2FF (767) is:

```
 767,   "Elevation Required to View"
```

If the call succeed, the code checks one of the parameter which is definitly an `out` parameter:

```
.text:00000001400142EC                 call    cs:__guard_dispatch_icall_fptr
.text:00000001400142F2                 mov     esi, eax
.text:00000001400142F4                 test    eax, eax
.text:00000001400142F6                 js      loc_1400143F0
.text:00000001400142FC                 cmp     dword ptr [rsp+2C8h+var_254], ebx ; rbx = 0
.text:0000000140014300                 jnz     short loc_14001431D
.text:0000000140014302                 mov     edx, 3B8h
.text:0000000140014307                 lea     rcx, [rsp+2C8h+var_288]
.text:000000014001430C                 call    cs:__imp_?LoadStringW@CString@@QEAAHI@Z ; CString::LoadStringW(uint)
```

If it's 0, the string 0x3b8 (952) is used:

```
  952,  "Meets prerequisites"
```

Otherwise various failure functions are called.

## Failure

In case of a failure, the `UpdateDeviceEncryptionStateFailureString` function is called:

```
.text:0000000140014325                 lea     r9, [rsp+2C8h+var_294] ; int *
.text:000000014001432A                 lea     r8, [rsp+2C8h+var_290] ; int *
.text:000000014001432F                 mov     edx, 3C1h       ; unsigned int
.text:0000000140014334                 lea     rcx, [rsp+2C8h+var_288] ; struct CString *
.text:0000000140014339                 call    ?UpdateDeviceEncryptionStateFailureString@@YAXPEAVCString@@IPEAH1@Z ; UpdateDeviceEncryptionStateFailureString(CString *,uint,int *,int *)
```

Its main goal is to fetch some string from the resource file.

One that stands out is 0x3b9:

```
.text:0000000140013A37                 mov     edx, 3B9h
.text:0000000140013A3C                 mov     rcx, rbx
.text:0000000140013A3F                 call    cs:__imp_?LoadStringW@CString@@QEAAHI@Z ; CString::LoadStringW(uint)
```

```
  953,  "Reasons for failed automatic device encryption"
```

Which is the case for me since I don't have a TPM.

## Other Functions

All of the other functions called from the `DeviceEncryptionDataPoints` (at least to get the needed results) are all from the `fveapi.dll`.

There are a lot in a function called `PerformIndividualHardwareTests(HINSTANCE hModule, struct CString *, int *, int *)`:

```
.text:0000000140013AEF                 lea     rdx, aNgscbcheckisao ; "NgscbCheckIsAOACDevice"
.text:0000000140013AF6                 mov     [rbp+var_1F], 0
.text:0000000140013AFA                 mov     rdi, r9
.text:0000000140013AFD                 mov     [rbp+var_20], 0
.text:0000000140013B01                 mov     rsi, r8
.text:0000000140013B04                 mov     [rbp+var_1E], 0
.text:0000000140013B08                 mov     rbx, rcx
.text:0000000140013B0B                 call    cs:__imp_GetProcAddress
.text:0000000140013B12                 nop     dword ptr [rax+rax+00h]
.text:0000000140013B17                 mov     r12, rax
.text:0000000140013B1A                 test    rax, rax
.text:0000000140013B1D                 jz      loc_140013CB9
.text:0000000140013B23                 lea     rdx, aNgscbcheckishs ; "NgscbCheckIsHSTIVerified"
.text:0000000140013B2A                 mov     rcx, rbx        ; hModule
.text:0000000140013B2D                 call    cs:__imp_GetProcAddress
.text:0000000140013B34                 nop     dword ptr [rax+rax+00h]
.text:0000000140013B39                 mov     r15, rax
.text:0000000140013B3C                 test    rax, rax
.text:0000000140013B3F                 jz      loc_140013CB9
.text:0000000140013B45                 lea     rdx, aNgscbcheckhsti ; "NgscbCheckHSTIPrerequisitesVerified"
.text:0000000140013B4C                 mov     rcx, rbx        ; hModule
.text:0000000140013B4F                 call    cs:__imp_GetProcAddress
.text:0000000140013B56                 nop     dword ptr [rax+rax+00h]
.text:0000000140013B5B                 mov     r13, rax
.text:0000000140013B5E                 test    rax, rax
.text:0000000140013B61                 jz      loc_140013CB9
.text:0000000140013B67                 lea     rdx, aNgscbcheckdmas ; "NgscbCheckDmaSecurity"
.text:0000000140013B6E                 mov     rcx, rbx        ; hModule
.text:0000000140013B71                 call    cs:__imp_GetProcAddress
```

There's also a registry key checked `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BitLocker\AutoDE\HSTI`:

```
.text:0000000140013C10                 lea     r8, ?NGSCB_AUTODE_HSTI_REQUIRED@@3QBGB ; "HSTIVerificationRequired"
.text:0000000140013C17                 mov     [rsp+60h+pcbData], rax ; pcbData
.text:0000000140013C1C                 lea     rdx, ?NGSCB_AUTODE_HSTI_PREREQS@@3QBGB ; "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Bit"...
.text:0000000140013C23                 lea     rax, [rbp+var_1C]
.text:0000000140013C27                 mov     r9d, 10h        ; dwFlags
.text:0000000140013C2D                 mov     [rsp+60h+pvData], rax ; pvData
.text:0000000140013C32                 mov     rcx, 0FFFFFFFF80000002h ; hkey
.text:0000000140013C39                 and     [rsp+60h+var_40], 0
.text:0000000140013C3F                 call    cs:__imp_RegGetValueW
```

and some other functions (`NgscbCheckPreventDeviceEncryption`, `NgscbGetWinReConfiguration`, `FveCheckTpmCapability`, ...) , once again, all from the `fveapi.dll` module.

So basically the checks are all based on functions from this DLL. It seems that none of them are documented (as far as I can see with a quick search).

I didn't find anything around in the `DeviceEncryptionDataPoints` caller (which is basically the main() function), since the next calls are dealing with checking the hypervisor capabilities.